# Proving that ord $(g, \frac1{z_0}) = n$ where $z_0 > 0$ and $g(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

Proving the following relation:

Suppose that $\operatorname{ord}(f,z_0)=n$ with $z_0$ not $0$. So letting $g(z)=f\left(\dfrac1z\right)$, I have that $\operatorname{ord}\left(g,\dfrac1{z_0}\right)=n$.

Does I have anything to do with singularities of $g$?

Is there a simple proof of this. I need help proving that it is a valid statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ has zero of order $n$ at $z_0$ iff there is an open disk containing $z_0$ in which $f(z)=(z-z_0)^{n} g(z)$ for some holomorphic function $g$ in the disk with no zeros.

If $z_0 \neq 0$ this gives $g(z)=\frac {z_0^{n}} {z^{n}} (z-\frac 1 {z_0})^{n} g(\frac 1  z)$ in some disc around $\frac  1 {z_0}$. This proves that $g$ has a zero of order $n$ at $\frac  1 {z_0}$.